# Adding reference to assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

int [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page at the beginning of the Walkthrough

1. Create a WPF Application project named HostingWfInWpf.
2. Add references to the following assemblies. WindowsFormsIntegration and System.Windows.Forms

In the second task what are they reffering to? Where are those assemblies in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Those are .Net assemblies.**

Right click on **`References`** folder in your project and click on **`Add Reference`**.
It will open a popup to select assembly reference, select **`.Net`** tab from it and search for the assemblies (*WindowsFormsIntegration and System.Windows.Forms*) you want to add and click OK.

Comment: They want me to add references of those assemblies "into" my project. When they say add references to following assemblies I was thinking how to add reference to something we add reference for. It is about not understanding the sentence=) Shame on me. Thank you. I will check you answer as correct.

Comment: Yeah happens sometimes.. :)